# Find out unused imports on a React Native project

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, visual-studio-code

I imported the following `React Native` project into `VS Code`.

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/tree/master/example

Then, on the following file, on line 15:

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/blob/master/example/src/CardExample.js#L15

I added (just experimenting), the line:

```
import { StatusBar, I18nManager, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
```

as you can see on the code below:

```
/* @flow */

import * as React from 'react';
import { Alert, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {
    Title,
    Caption,
    Paragraph,
    Card,
    Button,
    withTheme,
    type Theme,
} from 'react-native-paper';

import { StatusBar, I18nManager, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

type Props = {
    theme: Theme,
};

class CardExample extends React.Component<Props> {
    static title = 'Card';

    render() {
        const {
            theme: {
                colors: { background },
            },
        } = this.props;
        return (
            <ScrollView
                style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: background }]}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.content}
            >
                <Card style={styles.card}>
                    <Card.Cover source={require('../assets/wrecked-ship.jpg')} />
                    <Card.Content>
                        <Title>Abandoned Ship</Title>
                        <Paragraph>
                            The Abandoned Ship is a wrecked ship located on Route 108 in
              Hoenn, originally being a ship named the S.S. Cactus. The second
              part of the ship can only be accessed by using Dive and contains
              the Scanner.
            </Paragraph>
                    </Card.Content>
                </Card>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    content: {
        padding: 4,
    },
    card: {
        margin: 4,
    },
});

export default withTheme(CardExample);
```

**My problem is** that `VS Code` is not graying or highlighting out that new line with unused imports as you can see on the following image:

[image]

Is there an easy way for me to know about unused imports on this `React Native` project by either graying out these imports or by running some `npm` command on the command line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using eslint.

For install instruction see: https://medium.com/@deadcoder0904/eslint-setup-in-react-native-using-vscode-c3122a1da9c7

It will mark unused imports

[image]

Answer (score 0):

VSCode has build in [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) for show unused import or variables, you can enable/disable in setting section.

You can find setting section in:

On Windows/Linux - File > Preferences > Settings

On macOS - Code > Preferences > Settings

Check on `Show Unused` user setting in `Text Editor` section.
[image]